# Hexadecimal Characters in Encoded XML Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, encryption

I'm using following method to encrypt the data before storing them into database. The data will be converted to XML upon retrieval and  passed to data-access layer to be deserialized into a known business entity object.

The problem is there are some Hexadecimal characters in data due to encoding and that makes the xml an invalid xml document so it can't be deserialized.

How should I solve this problem?

```
public static string EncryptStringAES(string plainText, string sharedSecret)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sharedSecret))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sharedSecret");

    string outStr = null;                       // Encrypted string to return
    RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;              // RijndaelManaged object used to encrypt the data.

    try
    {
        // generate the key from the shared secret and the salt
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, _salt);

        // Create a RijndaelManaged object
        aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);

        // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // prepend the IV
            msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
            msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);
            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                {
                    //Write all data to the stream.
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                }
            }
            outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        // Clear the RijndaelManaged object.
        if (aesAlg != null)
            aesAlg.Clear();
    }

    // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
    return outStr;
}
```

Comment: I've tagged your question as C#, as I believe this is the language in use. Please correct if wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I usually use [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) to escape values for XML.

Comment: You mean I can't cure this method?

Comment: You can use this method to escape values from XML string, and on the client side use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode to decode value back. Also you can use [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) tag when you put this value into xml, and on the client side you will need to handle CDATA.

Comment: well, unfortunately HttpUtility didn't solve my problem. I'm still facing the same error.

Comment: Interesting, could you show sample or your string and the code how you place it in XML?

Comment: you mean a sample of XML generated by stored procedure? the serialization is done in c# after mapping the table type.

Comment: Ok, just string which you can get from EncryptStringAES which will invalid after you will apply HttpUtility.HtmlEncode

Comment: something like this:"EAAAAGKpTEdLDYmLS2Ejaz8xWz7kdA0m0xc0sP7UKrHD+LDR"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27756/discussion-between-outcoldman-and-elham)